# Animaciones en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animación

Me preguntaba si hay alguna manera de que cuando escribo "en stock:" no solo se escriba, si no que realice una animación o algo que se vea agradable

```
function carro(id,id2,stock){
    let a=0;
    a=stock-document.getElementById(id).value
    document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML='En stock: ',a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear una clase con css

```
.new { 
    background-color:yellow; 
}
```

y en tu funcion agregar

```
function carro(id,id2,stock){
    let a=0;
    a=stock-document.getElementById(id).value
    let element=document.getElementById(id2);
    element.innerHTML='En stock: ',a;
    element.classList.add("new"); 
    setTimeout(function(){ element.classList.remove("new") }, 3000);
}
```

Es solo una idea.